# doubt in cygwin commands

Tags: cygwin

how to go into the environment of "c". when using cygwin... please tell me the commands to go into the c environment....

Comment: You might want to add a little more detail about what you are trying to do...

Comment: Do you want to compile C programs?

Comment: It's right next to the environment of D, across the environment of C++.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to navigate to the C: drive when in the shell?  If so, just do `cd c:`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cd to the C: drive then one way is:

$ cd /cygdrive/c

If you want to edit/compile/run/debug C programs, then it's:

$ emacs foo.c # edit

$ gcc -Wall foo.c -o foo # compile

$ ./foo # run

$ gdb ./foo # debug

Answer (score 0):

Install cygwin from cygwin.org. Select development packages like gcc during the process. Open a cygwin shell and call gcc from the command line. Or whatever.

Comment: it's a pity we have to *guess* what the OP wants.

Comment: funny - it didn't occur to me she wants to navigate to c:

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question, my first interpretation was that the question was about how to ensure that the C locale was set for the shell in Cygwin, rather than allowing the Windows locale to be inherited. Putting `export LC_ALL=C` or `export LC_ALL=C.utf8` into your `~/.bashrc` would force the C locale in all shell contexts. The command `locale` can be used to see your current locale before and after changing `LC_ALL`, which will help verify that the change is in effect. `man bash` (or your shell of choice) will provide more information on what is affected by the various locale-related environment variables.